# Camel in action codehaus.mojo plugin error

Tags: java, maven, cmd, apache-camel, mojo

Hi I am learning Camel (using Camel in action). When I try to run a Maven command in cmd e.g. mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=camelinaction.GreetMeBean

I get an error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:java (default-cli) on project chapter2: An exception occured while executing the Java class. camelinaction.GreetMeBean -> [Help 1]

Apparently I am missing a plugin, but I don't understand how to get this plugin.

Comment: The errormessage says **An exception occured while executing the Java class. camelinaction.GreetMeBean** The whole message could help to find the reason why this is not working

Comment: Hi, the whole error is at --> https://shrib.com/23uzUjIhfEf1YWn

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml` since logs are indicating that `camel-spring` dependency is missing _java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.spring.Main_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run that command in the right directory, eg do

```
cd chapter2
cd spring
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=camelinaction.GreetMeBean
```